# Castle Windsor Interceptor

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, interception

I'm trying to use the code from this page, http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Introduction-to-AOP-With-Castle.ashx and register an interceptor in a fluent manner.
But I get this error thrown. I've tried Castle Windsor versions from 2.5 to 3.3. So it must be something very basic in how interceptors are set up

### Classes

```
public interface ISomething
{
    Int32 Augment(Int32 input);
    void DoSomething(String input);
    Int32 Property { get; set; }
}

class Something : ISomething
{
    public int Augment(int input) {
        return input + 1;
    }

    public void DoSomething(string input) {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm doing something: " + input);
    }

    public int Property { get; set; }
 }

public class DumpInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation) {
        Console.WriteLine("DumpInterceptorCalled on method " +
            invocation.Method.Name);
        invocation.Proceed();

        if (invocation.Method.ReturnType == typeof(Int32)) {
            invocation.ReturnValue = (Int32)invocation.ReturnValue + 1;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("DumpInterceptor returnvalue is " +
            (invocation.ReturnValue ?? "NULL"));
    }     
}
```

### Setup

```
Console.WriteLine("Run 2 - configuration fluent");
using (WindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer())
{
    container.Register(
        Component.For<IInterceptor>()
        .ImplementedBy<DumpInterceptor>()
        .Named("myinterceptor"));
    container.Register(
        Component.For<ISomething>()
        .ImplementedBy<Something>()
     .Interceptors(InterceptorReference.ForKey("myinterceptor")).Anywhere);


    ISomething something = container.Resolve<ISomething>(); //Offending row

    something.DoSomething("");

    Console.WriteLine("Augment 10 returns " + something.Augment(10));
}
```

### Error

> Type 'Castle.Proxies.ISomethingProxy' from
>   assembly'DynamicProxyGenAssembly2, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' is attempting to implement an inaccessible
>   interface.

Comment: Same thing if I add the interceptor with [Interceptor("myinterceptor")]

Comment: I just copy-pasted your code into a fresh console app and it works for me. Are you sure this is your code?

Comment: It actually solved itself after I placed each class and interface in its own file. I also removed and readded castle windsor. I think maybe they were internal classes before on the main class, I'm not sure. It works now though... That was a lot of hours wasted :). Thanks for trying though @YuvalItzchakov

Comment: yes, that was it. You can register and resolve inner classes but you can't add interceptors to them.. Hmm sneaky :)

Comment: @Chris, don't hesitate to clean up your code to keep only relevant info, and then post your latest comment as an answer, this really is an important point, which I'd upvote

Comment: @samy I updated the question with an answer headline to clearify exactly when it happens. I hope it's understandable

Comment: Chris, that's great. I think that it would be even better if you posted the "answer" section as an answer. You are encouraged to post answers even if you find them yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The answer

So I found why this was happening. Appearantly if you create inner classes and interfaces you can register and resolve them but attaching interceptors to them won't work

#### Example - where the error will be triggered

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(String [] args)
    {
        var container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.Register(Component.For<TestInterceptor>().Named("test"));
        container.Register(Component.For<InnerInterface>().ImplementedBy<InnerClass>().Interceptors(InterceptorReference.ForKey("test")).Anywhere);
        // this row below will throw the exception
        var innerClassInstance = container.Resolve<InnerInterface>();
    }

    class InnerClass : InnerInterface  { }

    interface InnerInterface { }

    class TestInterceptor : IInterceptor
    {
        public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

#### Conclusion

So to conclude my intention was not to create inner classes in the first place but rather put together a demo to showcase Castle Windsor. But maybe this can help someone if they run into the same error as me..